# All windows dropdowns close instantly

Tags: windows-7, window-focus

Any combobox I try to open in the system closes itself instantly after having slided open. This makes it impossible to select something in a combobox. An example combobox is the one allowing you to choose the type of document (doc, docx, rtf) in the 'Save As...' dialog box in MS Word (or Notepad or ...). It looks a bit like the focus is gone (or stolen by something else). Trying to navigate the combobox with the keyboard results in the same behavior.

After several hours of research I've found a couple of people on the internet experiencing the same issue, but none have posted a solution.
The most comprehensive thread I've found is [this one](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproui/thread/e2521890-870c-448b-89d0-ebc1748ae05b). It even has a [video](http://www.askesis.com/swf/dropdown/drop%20down%20issue.html) showing the exact same issue.

Own attempts to fix this:
The issue does NOT occur on a new (other) user account or when starting the computer in safe mode.
When using mconfig to disable all items on the 'startup' tab, the issue still occurs.
Changing keyboard and mouse to a spare one does not help either.

I would be most grateful if someone could help me out with this. If you want any more information; please ask!

Comment: Are you using a wireless mouse? If yes then you should be using a trackpad

Comment: No, it's a wired logitech MX-518. Tried it with Wired Logitech spare mouse too, same issue. Thank you for your interest however!

Comment: try with no mouse..??

Comment: Since it doesn't happen in safe mode what if you identified the processes that are running in safe mode and left those alone but killed the other processes one at a time until you find the culprit.

Comment: While it may not sound sensible, I find this to be graphics driver related - I imagine something fails in the window render.  Perhaps try upgrading your drivers?

Comment: @Mr47: Could you try resetting your Windows theme please? Right-click the desktop -> Personalize -> Theme

Comment: @James: Didn't think of that, but unfortunatly it didn't help.

Comment: @Paul: I've updated to the latest drivers, same issue. Note that a different user account does not have the issue (using the same driver I suppose?).

Comment: @CHarmon: The other user account is running exactly the same processes and does not have the issue. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @ahmed: No luck withouth a mouse :(